# Необходимо ли обособление приложения?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, приложение

«Это стихотворение написала Валя Грин на день рождения своей бабушки, Анастасии Михайловны Грин».
Нужна ли запятая после «бабушки»?

Answer (score 1):

Однозначность окончанию фразы задаёт притяжательное местоимение. Без него и без запятой бабушка становится не её (Вали), а Анастасии Михайловны. С ним (***своей** бабушки Анастасии*) запятая выглядит излишней.

Answer (score 1):

*Это стихотворение написала Валя Грин на день рождения своей бабушки, **Анастасии Михайловны Грин.***

При постановке запятой имя **уточняет нарицательное существительное**. Обычно это **авторский выбор**, но в данном случае постановка запятой желательна в связи с распространенностью всего предложения. Смысл такой: а зовут ее бабушку Анастасия Михайловна Грин.

Розенталь, [Обособленные приложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111):

6. Собственное имя лица или кличка животного выступает в роли **обособленного** приложения, если **поясняет либо уточняет** нарицательное существительное (перед таким приложением можно без изменения смысла вставить слова *а именно, то есть, а зовут его*): *Дочь Дарьи Михайловны, **Наталья Алексеевна**, с первого взгляда могла не понравиться* (Т.)...